# Check if player exists error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I have this windows form code

```
private void StartGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (player.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter A player to proceed.");
    }
    else
    {
    //SQL Connection String
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Keith;Initial Catalog=SoftEngg;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            bool exists = false;

            // create a command to check if the username exists
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("player", player.Text);
                exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }

            // if exists, show a message error
            if (exists)
                MessageBox.Show(player.Text, "is used by another user.");
            else
            {
                // does not exists, so, persist the user
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PlayerData(PlayerName) values (@Playername)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Playername", player.Text);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

my goal is to alert the player and display the messagebox "player already exist" in the system. But my code doesn't seem to work. When I run the program I get an error over this code here:

```
exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
```

and the error says: (Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

How to fix this, please help.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player.Text);`  Also, if the query returns nothing, it can't turn that into an `int`, so you need to check for that.

Comment: thanks for reminding, but I still get an error over that code exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `select Count(*) from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player` if you want to use `ExecuteScalar`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem not was in the query.
i mean not in this `select * from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player`

you were getting the error because of `exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;`

**Cause:**
here you are trying to `convert` the output to `Integer`.
so, when `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` getting the `null` Value on that time you are getting the error.

Have to Remember

> ```
> SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar:
> ```
>
> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

you can use `select * from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player` but you must confirm that your first column of this table is a `NonNullable` column.

and your checking should be like

```
 exists = (cmd.ExecuteScalar()!=null)?true:false;
```

Or, you can try by selecting your primary key column.

```
select your_Primary_Key_Name from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player
```

and check

```
 exists = (cmd.ExecuteScalar()!=null)?true:false;
```

> [do not use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@player",SqlDbType.Varchar,200).Value=YourValue;
```

Comment: I guess we can do simply exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar()!=null;

Comment: @brykneval yes,good point,no need the use the conditional operator.i missed this. :)
thanks for the suggestion.